# How to call javascript function in code behind .cs file in Asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I tried to call the function ApplyCSS() which is in my SearchPage.ascx page inside the Script tag and in .CS file I am trying to call that function using the below code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Script", "ApplyCSS();", true);
```

but I am getting javascript runtime error object expected.

Comment: Closely look at the call-stack of the error to find out what causes the error. If you are using Google Chrome, press F12 and use the Developer Tools.

Answer (score 2):

The likely cause of this error is that `ApplyCSS();` isn't defined at the time when the function is called.

So, is the `ApplyCSS();` function defined in a .js file? If so, you have to go with this kind of approach:

`$(document).ready(function () { ApplyCSS(); } );`

You'll need jQuery to do this

Comment: This basically boils down to where in your source the script-block is generated (hint: look at in your <head> or around your <form>-tag) and the location of the ApplyCSS() declaration. This answer will queue the call, executing after the (presumed) parsing of your ApplyCSS-code. Another solution would be to assure that the loading of your external js-file occurs before the call to ApplyCSS().

Answer (score 1):

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function MyFunc(){
};
</script>


 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, Page.GetType(), "key", "MyFunc()", true);
```

Semicolon is not required after MyFunc() Call.
You can refer [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=200) link

Comment: The semicolon may not be required, but note that several calls to RegisterStartupScript may result in .NET concatenating all code blocks into one larger block. Use semicolons for happy cooperation with other callers.

Answer (score 0):

Have your script line is should be

```
<script type='text/javascript' language="javascript">
//ApplyCSS();
</script>
```

and please check your function is does not threw any error.

and try with this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Script", "javascript:ApplyCSS();", true);
```